# Choose 2 numbers then find the nth number

Tags: vb.net

"Write a program which reads in a start and an end value.  The program then stores all the even numbers between these two values (inclusive) in an array.  The user is then asked to select a number (n), the program should output the nth even number"

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        number1 = InputBox("Enter first number")
        number2 = InputBox("enter second number")
```

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated, I'm completely lost.

Comment: If n1 = n2, then count will always be zero, why are you subtracting them? The only nth term mathematical sequence equation I can think of wouldn't produce 5 given those inputs, so can you explain mathematically what you're trying to accomplish in a bit more detail? The difference between 1 and 10 is 9 right? So where does the jump to five come from; that's not the 2nd term of the sequence so I'm a bit confused...

Comment: Found the task again, That should be more clear I'm new to vb.net and so confused with this one task I haven't had problems with any others that I have been given. This is just starting to bug me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the edit is making more sense to me now. You were on the right track getting the first three inputs. Then we neeed to do 2 things to our inputs:

> 1) Get the even numbers within the range the user has given us
>
> 2) Return the nth term if it exists

I would approach the problem like this:

```
    'Get our inputs
    Dim number1 As Integer = CInt(InputBox("Enter first number"))
    Dim number2 As Integer = CInt(InputBox("Enter second number"))
    Dim nthTerm As Integer = CInt(InputBox("Enter Nth Term"))
    Dim evenNumbers As New List(Of Integer)

    'Now, we want to get a list of all the even numbers within n1 to n2 range
    For i As Integer = number1 To number2
        'if the number divided by 2 has a remainder of 0, then it's an even number
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then evenNumbers.Add(i)
    Next

    'Now that we have all the even #s, try to return the nth one as long as it exists
    Try
        'We substract 1 from the nthTerm entered by used to account for list's 0-based index
        MsgBox(evenNumbers(nthTerm - 1).ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Nth Term out of bounds")
    End Try
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it that makes it so much easier to understand.